# Typo3 ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick

Tags: imagemagick, typo3, graphicsmagick, typo3-6.1.x

I have installed Typo3 6.1 on my webserver.
But now I am having problems with IM or GM.
In the install Tool in Image Processing all tests fail with the message:
"There was no result from the ImageMagick operation"

I have checked everything but I dont know what to do. Earlier versions of Typo3 worked without problems.

This are my settings.

On Basic configuration:

```
Available ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick installations:
/usr/local/bin/     gm 1.1.15
convert 6.8.0-7
composite 6.8.0-7
identify 6.8.0-7
[GFX][gdlib] = 1
[GFX][im_version_5] = gm
```

Edit: And yes I can execute an exec command within an php on my webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with a new search of the GM files in the basic configuration.